# NSString not showing correctly when loading data from csv file to xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a csv file that stores 3 values - a city name together with the state, the longitudes and latitudes values.

A sample data as appeared when I open with excel would be: Boston, Mass., 411.932, 73

The first problem that I face is that when I copy the csv file to the xcode project folder, xcode displays the file data as "Albany, N.Y.",397.898,73, adding "" to the first column data.

The second problem that I face is that when I retrieve the data from the csv file and pose the city name as a NSString, the string only shows Albany instead of Albany, N.Y.

Here's what I did. Thank you for your help.

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"citiesdataUsed" ofType:@"csv"];
NSString* fileContents =  [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSArray* pointStrings = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
cityList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//skip line 0 as it is the title of each column
for(int idx = 0; idx < pointStrings.count; idx++)
{
    Pair *sth = [[Pair alloc] init];
    // break the string down even further to the columns. 
    NSString* currentPointString = [pointStrings objectAtIndex:idx];
    NSArray* arr = [currentPointString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@","]];

    NSString *country = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [arr objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSNumber *latData = [[NSNumber alloc]  initWithFloat:[[arr objectAtIndex:2] floatValue]]; //long
    NSNumber *longData = [[NSNumber alloc]  initWithFloat:[[arr objectAtIndex:1] floatValue]]; //lat

    //convert the NSNumbers to float value
    float longData2 = [longData floatValue];
    float latData2 = [latData floatValue];
    CGPoint temp = CGPointMake(longData2,latData2);
    sth.city = country;
    sth.location = temp;
    [cityList addObject: sth];
    [sth release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to your country parsing only the first part..

You are splitting the line by `,` therefore your array would look like

```
arr[0] = Albany
arr[1] = N.Y.
arr[2] = 397.898
arr[3] = 73
```

Your code should show as

```
NSString *country = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@, %@", [arr objectAtIndex:0], [arr objectAtIndex:1]];
NSNumber *latData = [[NSNumber alloc]  initWithFloat:[[arr objectAtIndex:2] floatValue]]; //long
NSNumber *longData = [[NSNumber alloc]  initWithFloat:[[arr objectAtIndex:3] floatValue]]; //lat
```

Not too sure why xcode is including the quotes in your CSV file but if the quotes only display in xcode and not in (as an example) textedit, your file will be ok.

Comment: it appears to have quotes in textedit too but not in excel. That's weird. And for the arr, if my first array contains "Albany, N.Y.", does that mean that when I parse the first part they will the "," after Albany will skip the N.Y. and only parse Albany to NSString?